# Looking for a Text Editor that doesn't truncate a file prematurely

Tags: text-editor

I'm trying to find a decent text editor.  I've tried the following apps (in order of preference): [TxtPad Lite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.patillosoftware.apps.txtpadlite), [Scribtor Notes](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.tecxten.scribtor.free), [AmbleLink Notepad](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.objectvista.notepad)

All of them truncate the text file at 9025 bytes.  The file is fully there, I've verified it with `cat` from within Terminal Emulator.  Is it a limitation of whatever common text display widget they use or something?  It's really annoying...

EDIT: After trying AK Notepad I got to thinking that maybe it was something with the text files themselves (this is happening on multiple files).  Each paragraph of text was a single line and each file had Unix-style line endings (line feeds).  I first changed it so that each paragraph was formatted with LFs in all the right places; each text editor displayed exactly 1 more character than previous, in terms of the text (it was many more characters in terms of bytes, though, given all of the added LFs.  Next I tried converting from LF to CR/LF (DOS-style endings).  Now I got a dozen more characters of text (which was, again, many more bytes) but they all end at exactly the same spot.  I'm really at a loss to explain it.

EDIT: I found and tried [Amoeba](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.softevol.amoeba) and it has no problem with the file; it displays the original file (and the other versions) with no problems.  But the interface is not that great (in particular, scrolling is exceptionally tedious).  Any ideas out there?

Comment: What phone are you trying this on?

Comment: Galaxy-S (Vibrant, if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out "Need To Write" in the Market! I just wrote this app so i'm shamelessly advertising it everywhere. I was facing the same problems, so I made it to have no file size limit other than your sdcard size. NTW lets you display and edit files small chunks of the file at a time.

Comment: Be mindful of the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq): *"May I promote products I am affiliated with here?"*

Comment: I've downloaded the app but...how do I open an existing file with it?  Maybe I need some coffee...

Comment: Looks like you can open up existing files via a file manager like Astro.  And it does work, so...checkered flag for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try [AK Notepad](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.akproduction.notepad).  I'm not sure what the upper limit is, but I know I was able to create a 30kb file in there no problem.

Comment: How bizarre -- I'm having the same issue as before, truncating at exactly the same place.